# xmlwriter writedoctype formatting

Tags: .net, xml, powershell, doctype

I'm trying to generate this doctype string:

```
<!DOCTYPE games SYSTEM "transform.dtd">
```

This is what I've been trying:

```
$writer.WriteDocType("games", $null , "transform.dtd", $null )
```

I'm not entirely sure how to get that exact line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a known bug in PowerShell: [passing null to a string parameter results in a String.Empty instead of null.](http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/307821/it-isnt-possible-to-pass-null-as-null-into-a-net-method-that-has-a-parameter-of-type-string#)

You can work around it like this:

```
# Given an XML writer of some sort ...
$writer = [system.xml.xmlwriter]::create("$pwd\test.xml")

# Set up the parameters you want to pass to the method:
$params = @("games",$null,"transform.dtd",$null)

# And invoke it using .Net reflection:
$writer.GetType().GetMethod("WriteDocType").Invoke($writer,$params)

# Eventually, close the writer:
$writer.Close()
```